# smint jquery refresh page and nav stays where you were insted of reseting.

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

Im using smint jquery sticky nav, here is link to home page [here](http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/). I noticed that if you scroll down a little and refresh the page, the nav loads where you refreshed the page instead of back at the top, take a look and try it, maybe someone has a solution. I found a few people asking the same question but with know answers yet. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about "smint", but using jQuery, you could set the scroll position of the page to the top when the page loads, like this:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb9U6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

What this should do is, wait for the page to load, and then set the scroll position to the top of the window.

If this doesn't happen to work because the browser sets the scroll position after your jQuery executes or something, you could try setting the scroll position to the top before refreshing the page, that way when it refreshes and goes to the previous scroll position, that will be the top of the page anyways.

Comment: That's what I saw a few people talking about, but when I add your code, on refresh the page does go back to top only the nav says behind where you were.

Comment: I notice that on the smint homepage, they include this script: `<script>
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});</script>`. Their page scrolls back to the top and the nav goes back to its default position. Their Demo page, however, shows the problem that you're experiencing. So you're definitely not alone with this problem. Perhaps you can reverse-engineer whatever they did to fix it on their homepage and figure it out that way.

Answer (score 1):

at the bottom of the jquery.smint file before the last

```
  })();
```

add

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      stickyTop = 0;
  });
```